# Advanced number theory book recommendation

Tags: number-theory, book-recommendation

I have extensively studied number theory at high school level for various Olympiad Competitions. I am currently in undergrad 1st year, and I want to study number theory from the part I left behind, can someone suggest me some books on Advanced Number theory?

Comment: How about A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory by Ireland and Rosen. Very popular book.

Comment: It would help to know what specifically you know right now. Not just in number theory, but other areas of math. Most advanced areas of number theory use either abstract algebra or complex analysis, for example.

Comment: This is not a broad introduction, but it will empower you to think in new ways (visually, geometrically, ...) about number theory, and hence is of great value:  ***An illustrated theory of numbers*** by Martin Weissman.